# There's some way to know whats is the $document_root on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have created a new NGINX VHOST called `lottaleben.test` in my .conf and also seted php cgi conf but apparently he's always calling index.php from server_name localhost.

There's some way to know the $document_root value ?

`nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    #sendfile          on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip               on;

    #default
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         "c:/dev";

        location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass              127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index            index.php;
            include  fastcgi_params;
       }
    }

    include sites/*.conf;

}
```

`lottaleben.conf` -> that is project i  am trying call (inside sites/*.conf)

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  lottaleben.test;
        root   "c:/dev/lottaleben.test";

        location / {
           index  index.php index.html index.htm;
       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

in the `hosts` file in `c:/windows/System32/drives/etc` i have setted like:

`127.0.0.1 lottaleben.test www.lottaleben.test`

EDIT 1: seems always i call lottaleben.test, redirects me to index.php inside `c:/dev` and not to c:/dev/lottaleben.test` that contains index.php totally diferent.

EDIT 2: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` is setted inside `fastcgi_params` file.

Comment: server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         "c:/dev/lottaleben.test";

Comment: Thanks for advise me. I already try this but still calling same index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I found error. In `php.ini` i seted `doc_root = "c:/dev"`. I had no knowledge to say why this was `bugging` but after comented this line and refresh php-fpm everything works fine.